# Does NodeJS Gmail-Api quickstart method works in cloud server?

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm building a web app to get all my emails and getting transaction from it, my app is completely working in localhost, but if i deploy on cloud server Gmail Api is not calling its on request pending.

I deployed my server at cloud all other Api's are working, only this /gmail api is not working, if i ping this api in network tab it shows pending.

NodeJS

```
const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"];

    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "token.json");
    const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "credentials.json");

    /**
     * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
     *
     * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
     */
    async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
      try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
      } catch (err) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
     *
     * @param {OAuth2Client} client
     * @return {Promise<void>}
     */
    async function saveCredentials(client) {
      const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
      const keys = JSON.parse(content);
      const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
      const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: "authorized_user",
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
      });
      await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
    }

    /**
     * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
     *
     */
    async function authorize() {
      let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
      if (client) {
        return client;
      }
      client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
      });
      if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
      }
      return client;
    }

userRouter.get(
  "/gmail",
  protect,
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
    
    const auth = await authorize(req.user._id);
    const transactions = await listInboxEmails(auth, req);
    res.send(transactions);
    for (const transaction of transactions) {
      const { merchantName, date, time } = transaction;
      const existingTransaction = await Transaction.findOne({
        user: req.user._id,
        merchantName,
        date,
        time,
      });
      if (!existingTransaction) {
        await Transaction.create(transaction);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Lists all the inbox emails of the user.
     *
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
     */
    async function listInboxEmails(auth) {
      const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });

      // Get the list of messages in the user's inbox
      const res = await gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: "me",
        q: 'subject:"Transaction Success Alert - Debit Card Transaction at Merchant Establishment"',
      });

      if (!res.data.messages || res.data.messages.length === 0) {
        console.log("No messages found.");
        return [];
      }

      const transactions = [];

      // For each message, get the full message details and extract the relevant information
      for (const message of res.data.messages) {
        const fullMessage = await gmail.users.messages.get({
          userId: "me",
          id: message.id,
        });
        const messageBody = fullMessage.data.snippet; // Get the message body

        // Extract amount, merchant name and date
        const amount = messageBody.match(/transaction of Rs\.([\d.]+)/i)?.[1];
        const merchantName = messageBody.match(/(?<=at )(.*)(?= on)/)?.[0];
        const date = messageBody.match(/on (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/i)?.[1];
        const timeMatch = messageBody.match(
          /on \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\./
        );
        const time = timeMatch
          ? `${timeMatch[1] % 12 || 12}:${timeMatch[2]}:${timeMatch[3]} ${
              timeMatch[1] >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"
            }`
          : null;

        // Check if all three pieces of information were found
        if (amount && merchantName && date && time) {
          const categoryKeys = Object.keys(merchantCategoryMap);
          let category = merchantCategoryMap[merchantName] || "Other";
          if (category === "Other") {
            const merchantWords = merchantName.split(" ");
            for (const word of merchantWords) {
              if (categoryKeys.includes(word)) {
                category = merchantCategoryMap[word];
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          const transaction = {
            user: req.user._id,
            category,
            merchantName,
            amount: parseFloat(amount),
            date,
            time,
          };
          transactions.push(transaction);
        }
      }

      return transactions;
    }
'''
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: are you using the gmail api or imap?

Comment: Gmail-API @LindaLawton-DaImTo

Comment: Welcome to stack I have fixed your tags for you.   dont tag things to imap if your not using imap